# Migrate from Ember Start Kit (not appkit) to Ember.cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a node.js backend server and an ember front-end project which is together:

```
public\js -> contains all the ember app stuff
app\ -> contains the node.js files
server.js -> main express server code
```

I would like to migrate to use ember-cli. I've tried the migrator and running ember init but both do not really work and give me errors. Most the documentation talks about migrating from EmberAppKit which I didn't use, but use my own grunt script to complie the templates and uglify and minify the css and js files.

How should I go about migrating such a project to Ember-cli? I'm very confused..please help.

Thanks!

Comment: This is rather too broad for stack overflow, the process isn't exactly easy and needs to be done in steps (migrate 1 thing at a time, move the controller/model/component/styles etc).

Comment: @Kitler ok, wonderful, then where do I start from? I've watched presentations, read ember cli site, and I'm still super confused (and I've been doing ember for 1.5 years too)

Comment: Are you familiar with the [ember-cli naming conventions](http://www.ember-cli.com/#naming-conventions)?

Comment: a little but not too much..

Comment: @kitler why do you think its too broad?? I tried to ask on ember-cli and got directed here

Comment: Because this question is not about a programming problem and cannot be answered in a simple and precise manner, what you need is someone to walk you through it making it too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: @Kitler well I think this is a question that would require some guidance and I think that directing to a post would be very helpful..and migrating your code to ember cli is not programming??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81371/discussion-between-kitler-and-dory-zidon).